# Migrating from EF 6.1.2 to EF Core (2.1). How to deal with the Migrations?

Tags: entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations, ef-database-first

As performance of our application is lack lustre we may try to migrate it from using Entity Framework 6.1.2 to Entity Framework Core 2.1. I cannot find a clear overview what pitfalls there will be. I do not expect too much problems arising from the need to rewrite some queries, but I am especially wondering what needs to be done about our 30+ migrations that we have for the database.

Are there examples on how to migrate Migrations from EF 6 to EF-core 2.1?

Answer (score 1):

If you have EF 6 as Database-First and EF Core is Code-First. You can use [reverse POCO generator](https://github.com/ErikEJ/SqlCeToolbox/wiki/EF-Core-Power-Tools). Then run `Add-Migration` to generate migration. Now you have to take care, You need to remove the changes from Up method. Now run `Update-Database`. From now onwards follow Code-first approach. you make changes in model, generate migration and run `Update-Database`.

Welcome yo EF Core.

Comment: @magicandre1981 didn’t knew this, updated question accordingly. Thanks